# How to implemented clientaccesspolicy.xml for WCF Restfull Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I have implemeted a WCF Rest full service. and I have also configure it to crossdomain but now my prob is how to secure it.

I am calling that service using AJAX,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:52823/Handler/RequestService/GetPeople", function (data) {

            $("#response").append(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    });
```

now as I am calling from ajax so my service link visible to every one in browser so anyone can call that service and get that data.

So I have google it find that we can put the clientaccesspolicy.xml to the root folder of server and we can configure the specific domain. so I have tried it using below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <access-policy>
<cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
        <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
            <domain uri="myipaddress or domainname"/>
        </allow-from>
        <grant-to>
            <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
        </grant-to>
    </policy>
</cross-domain-access>
```

but it's not working so can anyone plese help me out to secure the WCF service.

Comment: Did my advice help you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting you application on IIS you can just add to you web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

For Access-Control-Allow-Origin you can set you application address:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.com, http://domain2.com

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://domain1.com" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

You can also reach the goal, writing behaviour which adds a specific header to each message. Here is a guide:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx

There is a constant CorsConstants.Origin, you can set your domain instead.

To check if response has required header you can use fiddler.